# How can a noob understand 'where their money went' when buying from bittylicious?

Tags: transaction-fees

Complete newbie, trying out bitcoin for the first time (probably like everyone else in the world this morning).

Wanted to spend the maximum allowed for a new user - about 43 pounds.

When the full transaction details came up, I was being offered to buy 2.9 mBTC for this amount - at the bitcoin rate at the time, that was only about 33 dollars' worth of bitcoin - so, about 24 pounds!

On the face of it, the transaction results in me losing half my money!
How can I tell where that money 'goes'? Is it a transaction fee, or am I somehow just paying a strange price?

Comment: Can you share the transaction id?

Comment: @asterisk https://blockchain.info/tx/5d86a7641a5b729708f27ffe41c195a3ec9beb0f3ee270ed381cc02cd114670d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the transaction link provided ([link](https://blockchain.info/tx/5d86a7641a5b729708f27ffe41c195a3ec9beb0f3ee270ed381cc02cd114670d))

You can see that fees was just below $2 for this transaction:

[image]

So the rest (about 18 pounds) have been taken as a commission/fees for using their interface.

I would suggest you to try some other website to buy BTC, as you are paying a very high fees to buy BTC.